# Disable all Styles inside iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

How do I disable all css styles from the parent site inside an iframe, so it remains completely unstyled of the parents css.

Comment: When you don't use the `seamless` attribute none of the styles of the parent site should be found inside the iframe.

Comment: you cant do it unless iframe provider allow you to do it

Comment: If the iframe contains body > ul > li > asdftest, I can style it with body > ul{ somecss }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with parent site

Assuming that iframe content coming from your domain, and you can change in that.

So you can do this with [Css reset](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/)

You have to include css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.17.2/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">
```

And add your CSS after the user's CSS, so that yours is evaluated last. Then, reset the CSS on your elements by giving them a class attribute like this:

```
class="yui3-cssreset"
```

Comment: if iframe loads remote page then how to disable all css?

Answer (score 1):

If it's on the same domain (cross-domain security will prevent you from making any changes otherwise), you could use jQuery to select the style blocks and links to CSS:

Just point the selector at your iFrame and remove the style and links from the document:

```
$('#myFrame').contents().find('head link').remove();
$('#myFrame').contents().find('style').remove();
```

In a single line:

```
$('#myFrame').contents().find('head link, style').remove();
```

That should clear up any CSS styles. If there are inline styles though - that will require more work.

Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/JohnSReid/qv6q6ed8/1/show/

Comment: The problem is the css above the iframe not the styles inside it. The parent effects the iframe, which is unwanted.

Comment: The parent document's CSS doesn't pass into the iframe. The iframe is an entirely separate document.

Comment: Added a link to JS fiddle which shows two different paragraph styles on the parent and the iframe document. Unless you're explicitly styling that iframe elsewhere - you shouldn't be inheriting any styles from the parent.